# Python Tkinter как ввести текст в виджет пользовательского ввода заранее?

Tags: python, tkinter

Чтобы в коде программы уже был прописан текст, который будет введён. Мне нужен полноценно введённый текст (который можно скопировать) и фоновый (тусклый, как образец того, что должно быть написано)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
v.set("hello world")
e = Entry(root, textvariable=v)
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820178/how-to-add-placeholder-to-an-entry-in-tkinter):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

my_entry = Entry(root, width=50)
my_entry.pack()
my_entry.insert(0, "Place Holder")
my_entry.configure(state=DISABLED)

def on_click(event):
    my_entry.configure(state=NORMAL)
    my_entry.delete(0, END)

    # make the callback only work once
    my_entry.unbind('<Button-1>', on_click_id)

on_click_id = my_entry.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)

root.mainloop()
```

or

```
import tkinter as tk

class EntryWithPlaceholder(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="PLACEHOLDER", color='grey'):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.placeholder_color = color
        self.default_fg_color = self['fg']

        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.foc_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.foc_out)

        self.put_placeholder()

    def put_placeholder(self):
        self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color

    def foc_in(self, *args):
        if self['fg'] == self.placeholder_color:
            self.delete('0', 'end')
            self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color

    def foc_out(self, *args):
        if not self.get():
            self.put_placeholder()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tk.Tk() 
    username = EntryWithPlaceholder(root, "username")
    password = EntryWithPlaceholder(root, "password", 'blue')
    username.pack()
    password.pack()  
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А можно задать фоновый текст, который будет как образец текста, который нужно вводить? Который исчезает после ввода первого символа

Comment: @MrPikokon Вот так можно сделать placeholder см ответ